# convert a javascript library to AMD

Tags: javascript, requirejs, js-amd, libphonenumber

I'm trying to use a library -- [Google's libphonenumber](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) -- in my require application that is not AMD. What is the best way to consume this? I know I can create a module like this:

```
define(['module'], function (module) {
    // insert and return library code here.
});
```

But that doesn't seem great. It seems like I would have to refactor some of their code to get that working (e.g., turn it all into an object and return that object). I see a lot of libraries using a different pattern where they use an immediately invoked function that defines the module on the window object and returns it.

```
(function() {

    var phoneformat = {};

    window.phoneformat = phoneformat;

    if (typeof window.define === "function" && window.define.amd) {
        window.define("phoneformat", [], function() {
            return window.phoneformat;
       });
    }

})();
```

** UPDATE **
Is there any reason not to just do this?

```
define(['lib/phoneformatter'], function(phoneformatter) {

});
```

I get access to all of my methods but now it seems they are global because I did not wrap the library in a define...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ended up working for me:

```
define(['module'], function (module) {
    // insert and return library code here.
});
```

I am not entirely sure why 'module' was necessary. But it doesn't work without it. Also, I just returned an object and attached functions to it like so:

```
return {
    countryForE164Number: countryForE164Number,
    nextFunction: nextFunction,
    // more functions as needed.
}
```

There is not much in the way of documentation for using 'module' but from what I can ascertain: Module is a special dependency that is processed by requireJS core. It gives you information about the module ID and location of the current module. So it is entirely possible that I messed up the paths in config.

Answer (score 3):

Use RequireJS's [shim](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim). It'll look something like this

```
requirejs.config({
  shim: {
    'libphonenumber': {
      exports: 'libphonenumber' // Might not apply for this library
    }
  }
});
```

This will load `libphonenumber` and put its variables in the global scope

Comment: I don't know if I want everything in the global scope. This might be my misunderstanding of AMD, but I thought one of the benefits was privacy.

Comment: It depends on whether you're willing to rewrite the library slightly. For some libraries you can't, because of license issues. If you can't rewrite the library, then you'll have to live with variables in global scope. If you're willing to rewrite, see this post of mine -- http://ilinkuo.wordpress.com/2013/02/07/dojo-amd-incorporating-third-party-scripts/